# Android - Change from libgdx Activity to a "normal" Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, libgdx

How can I change from a libgdx Activity to a "normal" Activity when my Game is finished?

Answer (score 0):

You could start it using [startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) as described here: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html